# For Loop High CSRSS CPU

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have a batch file that takes an input file (in this case the file is a flat text file comprised of a file listing from a specified set of Windows XP system directories).

Then through a combination of a for loop to iterate through each file listed in the text file), setting a variable, using several call commands (in this case 9), and the find command to search the text file for files that appear in the output of other flat files.

The problem I am running into is that csrss.exe is using quite a bit of CPU processing.  In reading some other articles it seems that csrss has a relationship with command line processing.

What I want to know is if there is a better way to do this that will:

1. Reduce overall script time.
2. Reduce CPU load.

Below is a sample of the script:

```
:: ------------------------------------------------------
::  Running Multiple Commands
:: ------------------------------------------------------

for /f "delims=?" %%A in (dir-selected_tmp.txt) do (  
set filepath=%%A  
call :filepathparse  
call :md5hashchk  
call :versionchk  
call :densitychk  
call :processchk  
call :mutexchk  
call :networkchk  
call :injectedchk  
call :persistservicechk  
call :servicedllchk  
call :persistrunchk  
call :persistothchk  
call :unsigneddllchk  
call :filesysag  
)  
goto :comparison  

:: ####################################################################

:filepathparse
for %%B in ("%filepath%") do (
set filename=%%~nxB
)
goto :eof

:: ####################################################################

:md5hashchk

for /f "delims= " %%b in ('md5deep.exe "%filepath%"') do set hashvalue=%%b
goto :eof

:: ####################################################################

:versionchk

for /f "delims= " %%e in ('sigcheck.exe /accepteula -q -n "%filepath%"') do set versionvalue=%%e
goto :eof

:: ####################################################################

:densitychk

for /f "delims= " %%d in ('densityscout.exe -p 0.1 "%filepath%"') do set densityvalue=%%d
goto :eof

:: ####################################################################

:processchk

find.exe /I "%filepath%" %temp_outpath%\wmic-processes.txt > nul 2>&1 && goto processexist
set isprocess=NoActiveProc
goto :eof

:processexist
set isprocess=ActiveProc
goto :eof

:: ####################################################################

:mutexchk

if "%startup_chk%"=="-b" (
goto :mutexbl
)       

find.exe /I "%filepath%" %temp_outpath%\filesystem-handles_compared.txt > nul 2>&1 && goto mutexexist
set ismutex=NoNewActiveMutex
goto :eof   

:mutexexist
set ismutex=NewActiveMutex
goto :eof

:mutexbl

find.exe /I "%filepath%" %parsed_outpath%\filesystem-handles.txt > nul 2>&1 && goto mutexexist
set ismutex=NoNewActiveMutex
goto :eof   

:mutexexist
set ismutex=NewActiveMutex
goto :eof

:: ####################################################################

:networkchk

find.exe /I "%filename%" %temp_outpath%\tcpvcon_tmp.txt > nul 2>&1 && goto networkexist
set isnetwork=NoActiveNetwork
goto :eof

:networkexist
set isnetwork=ActiveNetwork
goto :eof

:: ####################################################################

:injectedchk

find.exe /I "%filepath%" %temp_outpath%\injecteddll_tmp.txt > nul 2>&1 && goto injectedexist
set isinjected=NoActiveInject
goto :eof

:injectedexist
set isinjected=ActiveInject
goto :eof

:: ####################################################################

:persistservicechk

find.exe /I "%filepath%" %temp_outpath%\autoruns-services_tmp.txt > nul 2>&1 && goto serviceexist
set isservice=NoInstalledService
goto :eof

:serviceexist
set isservice=InstalledService
goto :eof

:: ####################################################################

:servicedllchk
find.exe /I "%filepath%" %temp_outpath%\registry_hklm_installed_service_dlls_final.txt > nul 2>&1 && goto servicedllexist
set isservicedll=NoInstalledServiceDLL
goto :eof

:servicedllexist
set isservicedll=InstalledServiceDLL
goto :eof

:: ####################################################################

:persistrunchk

find.exe /I "%filepath%" %temp_outpath%\autoruns-run_tmp.txt > nul 2>&1 && goto runpersistexist
set isrunpersist=NoRunPersist
goto :eof

:runpersistexist
set isrunpersist=RunPersist
goto :eof

:: ####################################################################

:persistothchk

find.exe /I "%filepath%" %temp_outpath%\autoruns-oth_tmp5.txt > nul 2>&1 && goto persistothexist
set isothpersist=NoOtherPersist
goto :eof

:persistothexist
set ispersist=OtherPersist
goto :eof

:: ####################################################################

:unsigneddllchk

find.exe /I "%filepath%" %temp_outpath%\listdlls_temp2.txt > nul 2>&1 && goto unsigneddllexist
set isunsigneddll=NoUnSignedProcDLL
goto :eof

:unsigneddllexist
set isunsigneddll=UnSignedProcDLL
goto :eof

:: ####################################################################

:filesysag

:: Compiling Into Syslog Format 

 echo %datestamp%^|%currtime%^|%computername%^|%currip%^|%username%^|%lastlogintime%^|"%filepath%"^|%hashvalue%^|%versionvalue%^|%densityvalue%^|%isprocess%^|%ismutex%^|%isnetwork%^|%isinjected%^|%isservice%^|%isservicedll%^|%isrunpersist%^|%isothpersist%^|%isunsigneddll% >> %syslog_outpath%\%computername%-syslog.txt

 :: Compiling Into Parsed Format

echo "%filepath%"^|%hashvalue%^|%versionvalue%^|%densityvalue%^|%isprocess%^|%ismutex%^|%isnetwork%^|%isinjected%^|%isservice%^|%isservicedll%^|%isrunpersist%^|%isothpersist%^|%isunsigneddll% >> %parsed_outpath%\%computername%-filesystem.txt
goto :eof
```

Comment: Really need to look at your other called routines - especially `:unsigneddllchk` which would seem to be where you'd actually do something with the results of the previous checks. A sample of the files involved might also be helpful.

Comment: I can share some of those details.  There is another call after unsigneddllchk that basically takes all of the set variables from each call and echo's them to a flat text file.  So, you end up with something like: C:\Windows\system32\lsass.exe,ActiveProc,ActiveMutex,NoActiveNetwork,NoInjected.....etc.  This will iterate every file in the file list and use find.exe to see if that file exists in lets say the output of a process dump utility like pslist.  If it exists then it would be "ActiveProc", if not it would be "NoActiveProc.  Other utilities are getting the other data to compare.

Comment: Note that the commands referred to (such as pslist) have already gathered the relevant data and placed it in a flat file earlier in the script.  I just wanted to clarify that pslist was not running in the loop shown in my original post.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, your reluctance to provide further details means we are severely retricted on the amount of help we can offer.

I'd recommend:

First, build a list of the filepaths yu are interested in

```
(for /f "delims=?" %%A in (dir-selected_tmp.txt) do echo %%A )>paths_of_interest.txt
```

Then build temporary files containing a subset of the log data

```
findstr /I /g:paths_of_interest.txt %temp_outpath%\processes.txt >"%temp%\processes.x.txt"
```

Then re-process according to your original scheme, instead using `paths_of_interest.txt` and `"%temp%\processes.x.txt"`

This should reduce the amount of repetition, especially if you have long files.

---

```dos
:: ------------------------------------------------------
::  Running Multiple Commands
:: ------------------------------------------------------

:: Pre-processing

SET /a step=1000
SET /a dirstart=0
SET "dirskip="

:mainloop
SET /a dirsleft=0

SETLOCAL enabledelayedexpansion
(
 for /f "%dirskip%delims=?" %%A in (dir-selected_tmp.txt) do (
  SET /a dirsleft+=1
  IF !dirsleft! leq %step% ECHO %%A
 )
)>temp_dirs.txt
endlocal&SET /a dirsleft=%dirsleft%

FINDSTR /i /l /g:temp_dirs.txt "%temp_outpath%\wmic-processes.txt" >temp_filepathparse.txt
if "%startup_chk%"=="-b" (
 FINDSTR /i /l /g:temp_dirs.txt "%parsed_outpath%\filesystem-handles.txt" >temp_mutexchk.txt
) ELSE (
 FINDSTR /i /l /g:temp_dirs.txt "%temp_outpath%\filesystem-handles_compared.txt" >temp_mutexchk.txt
)
FINDSTR /i /l /g:temp_dirs.txt "%temp_outpath%\tcpvcon_tmp.txt" >temp_networkchk.txt
FINDSTR /i /l /g:temp_dirs.txt "%temp_outpath%\injecteddll_tmp.txt" >temp_injectedchk.txt
FINDSTR /i /l /g:temp_dirs.txt "%temp_outpath%\autoruns-services_tmp.txt" >temp_persistservicechk.txt
FINDSTR /i /l /g:temp_dirs.txt "%temp_outpath%\registry_hklm_installed_service_dlls_final.txt" >temp_servicedllchk.txt
FINDSTR /i /l /g:temp_dirs.txt "%temp_outpath%\autoruns-run_tmp.txt" >temp_persistrunchk.txt
FINDSTR /i /l /g:temp_dirs.txt "%temp_outpath%\autoruns-oth_tmp5.txt" >temp_persistothchk.txt
FINDSTR /i /l /g:temp_dirs.txt "%temp_outpath%\listdlls_temp2.txt" >temp_unsigneddllchk.txt

for /f "delims=" %%A in (temp_dirs.txt) do (  
set "filepath=%%A"  
call :filepathparse

....

call :filesysag  
)  

SET /a dirstart=%dirstart%+%step%
SET /a dirsleft=%dirsleft%-%step%
IF dirsleft gtr 0 SET dirskip=SKIP=%dirstart%&GOTO mainloop

goto :comparison
```

Then simply replace the filename in each of your routines `:processchk` to `:unsigneddllchk` with the corresponding `temp_whatever.txt` file created in the pre-processing. The switch on `mutex` is already done in the pre-processing.

This should reduce the searching done by the `find` command and hence the overall run time by selecting only those lines containing the target strings into the temp_* files created.

[Edit in response to further information provided]

Note the preprocessing block before the first `findstr` has been changed and that there is now a post-processing block between `call :filesysag  )` and `goto :comparison`

The object here is to reduce the size of the `temp_dirs.txt` file. I've arbitrarily chosen 1,000 (the size of `step`) but have no real idea of how big `step` should be. The larger it is, the quicker the process will be, but if it's too large, `temp_dirs.txt` will be too big for `findstr` to handle.

Note the use of the parsing trick on the line `endlocal&SET /a dirsleft=%dirsleft%` which uses the parsing system to move the modified value of `dirsleft` out of the `setlocal/endlocal` block.

Comment: Ok, I added the code in question.  Note that "dir-selected.txt" is a flat text file with just a directory listing using the commands  dir "C:\" /B /N /ON /S and dir "C:\" /B /N /ON /S /A:H.  The other files referenced in the find.exe structure are all again flat text files from the output of the commands run earlier in the script.  At issue is the loop I have (especially when the find command runs) spikes the CPU to 100%.  I need to find a better way to either structure the loop or run a different command other than find (such as grep) to get the same result. csrss.exe is the process at issue.

Comment: So, the problem I am having with your suggestion is that the FINDSTR fails to execute.  It is generating an error: "Search string too long".  Do I need to move the last ")" in "(for /f "delims=?" %%A in (dir-selected_tmp.txt) do ECHO %%A)>temp_dirs.txt" to somewhere later in the script, thus allowing it to parse one line at a time?  Right now it is trying to findstr in the entire file (which is 8000+ lines long...directory listing).